# Angular 6 best way to sequence functions that are not http oriented

Tags: angular, rxjs, synchronization

I am not strong with RxJS so am looking for guidance on how best to chain a sequence of simple non http.get etc. functions in Angular so that they happen in a synchronous fashion.

E.g. what is the 'best' way to run these in sequence in a component?

```
  function1() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello 1"); }, 3000);
  }

  function2() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello 2"); }, 6000);
  }

  function3() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello 3"); }, 1000);
  }

  function4() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello 4"); }, 750);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have async call, you can look for `forkJoin` from `rxjs`.

Here is the sample demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bqxg9x

Reference - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 2):

If the functions are synchronous (not async like an Http call) and don't return observables, then you can just call them in order and they will execute in order:

```
ngOnInit() {
  function1();
  function2();
  function3();
  function4();

}
```